# How to plot data from right to left in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I recently update the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library from 1.7.4 to 2.0.9 and I forgot what I did to customize the linechart to make the data displaying from right to left. Does anyone know? I am wondering if there is a method to call to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no method. But it can still be done because it only depends on how you add the data.

**Just add values at higher x-indices first.**

Say you got a chart with x-axis labels from January to December with an x-axis range from 0 - 11 (12 values).

Now add the december value at index 11, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for your quick reply. I actually asked a wrong question and my boss just corrected my mistake this morning. What I want is to have the first data point staying on the right hand side. The data will be still displaying from the left to the right, but the data should appear on the right hand side first. Thanks!

Comment: My boss actually likes to go with the way how it is. Thanks for your help and the library! =]

Comment: Also is there any way to make animation starts from right to left direction using animateX(1000, .LINEAR)?

Comment: Also if follow the same approch for line chart it crash with an exception negative size exception

Comment: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer.generateTransformedValuesLine(Transformer.java:178)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer.drawValues(LineChartRenderer.java:638)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:274)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22350)

Comment: Here is another solution I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76376641/how-to-plot-line-chart-in-reverse-direction-ie-starting-from-right-to-left-dire

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the first data point other than zero and have the data display in left to right manner use `moveViewToX(float xValue)`.

> `moveViewToX(float xValue)`: Moves the left side (edge) of the current viewport to the specified `xValue`.