# Android (MP Charts)

Tags: android

`

```
package m.com.mygraph;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SecondaryAxisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    LineChart lineChart;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary_axis);



        lineChart = findViewById(R.id.lineChart);



       //Disabling the drags from both axis
        lineChart.setDragXEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setDragYEnabled(false);



        //setting the X-axis position
        lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(10);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);

        //setting the draw grid lines on Xaxis to False
        lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);

        //removing the Y axis from the LHS
        lineChart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).setEnabled(false);

        //Aligning the Y-axis bottom with X-axis
        lineChart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT).setAxisMinimum(0);






        //setting data and design for the line to be drawn on graph
        LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(dataValues1(),"Data set 1");
        lineDataSet1.setColor(Color.RED);
        lineDataSet1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        lineDataSet1.setDrawCircles(true);
        lineDataSet1.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
        lineDataSet1.setDrawValues(true);
        lineDataSet1.setLineWidth(4);


        //setting data and design for the line to be drawn on graph
        LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(dataValues2(),"Data set 2");
        lineDataSet2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        lineDataSet2.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        lineDataSet2.setDrawCircles(true);
        lineDataSet2.setCircleColor(Color.GREEN);
        lineDataSet2.setDrawValues(true);
        lineDataSet2.setLineWidth(4);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(lineDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSet2);

        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        lineChart.setData(data);
        lineChart.invalidate();

       // lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    }

    private ArrayList<Entry> dataValues1()
    {
      ArrayList<Entry> dataVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
      dataVals.add(new Entry(1,20));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(2,24));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(3,2));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(4,10));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(5,28));

      return  dataVals;
    }

    private ArrayList<Entry> dataValues2()
    {
      ArrayList<Entry> dataVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
      dataVals.add(new Entry(1,15));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(2,18));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(3,5));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(4,6));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(5,35));

      return  dataVals;
    }
}
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqWf3.png)I want to create a chart in android application which has a Y-axis on Right Hand Side and X-axis labels are aligned from right to left aswell but I am stuck with X-axis not any way to arrange label right to left and there is another problem which you can see yourself aswell if you look closely
Y-axis zero is not aligned with X-axis, in fact, it is lying above.

I am attaching some pics.

Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated.[enter link description here][2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot data from right to left in MPAndroidChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809282/how-to-plot-data-from-right-to-left-in-mpandroidchart)

Comment: Hi Robert

I have tried doing it using moveViewToX(float xValue). But it is not working.

Comment: If you want to display your value in a decreasing order, just reverse your DataSet no?

Comment: I have tried that aswell  if I try doing that it simply throws an expection

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: m.com.mygraph, PID: 20129
                  java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -6

Comment: Can you share your code please? How do you reverse your DataSet ? How do you set your chart?

Comment: private ArrayList<Entry> dataValues1()
    {
      ArrayList<Entry> dataVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
      dataVals.add(new Entry(5,20));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(4,24));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(3,2));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(2,10));
      dataVals.add(new Entry(1,28));

      return  dataVals;
    }

Comment: lineChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(6);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem solved by creating X axis on top and Y axis on left hand side . Then
making Y axis inverted and then plot the graph ...once it is done .. rotate your entire graph by 180 degree ..it will give you a feel of a graph with Y scale on right hand side and x axis on bottom with plotting done from right to left ..(as ask in my question).

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to read the [base axis documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/axis-general/).
As you can see you ca use the function:

> setInverted(boolean enabled): If set to true, this axis will be
>   inverted which means the highest value will be on the bottom, the
>   lowest value on top.