# How to Plot Line Chart in reverse direction ie. starting from right to left direction in Android using MPAndroidChart library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

Hi I am using this library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart and trying to draw line chart from Endpoint to Start point that is from right to left direction, I followed library document and tried to implement below custom class code:

```
    class CustomLineChartRender(
    chart: LineDataProvider?,
    animator: ChartAnimator?, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?,
) : LineChartRenderer(chart, animator, viewPortHandler) {
    override fun drawHorizontalBezier(dataSet: ILineDataSet) {

        val phaseY = mAnimator.phaseY

        val trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.axisDependency)

        mXBounds[mChart] = dataSet

        cubicPath.reset()

        if (mXBounds.range >= 1) {
            var prev = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(mXBounds.max)
            var cur = prev

            // let the spline start
            cubicPath.moveTo(cur.x, cur.y * phaseY)
            //for (j in mXBounds.min + 1..mXBounds.range + mXBounds.min) {
            for (j in (mXBounds.min until mXBounds.max).reversed()) {
                prev = cur
                cur = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j)
                val cpx = (prev.x
                        - (prev.x - cur.x) / 2.0f)
                cubicPath.cubicTo(
                    cpx, prev.y * phaseY,
                    cpx, cur.y * phaseY,
                    cur.x, cur.y * phaseY)
            }
        }

        // if filled is enabled, close the path
        if (dataSet.isDrawFilledEnabled) {
            cubicFillPath.reset()
            cubicFillPath.addPath(cubicPath)
            // create a new path, this is bad for performance
            drawCubicFill(mBitmapCanvas, dataSet, cubicFillPath, trans, mXBounds)
        }
        mRenderPaint.color = dataSet.color
        mRenderPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        trans.pathValueToPixel(cubicPath)
        mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(cubicPath, mRenderPaint)
        mRenderPaint.pathEffect = null
    }
}
```

But above code stops animation `lineChart.animateX(1000, Easing.EasingOption.Linear)`starting from right direction at all. Any pointer will be appreciated!!

Current behavior is Line chart start rendering from Left to Right direction and
Expected behavior is Line chart should start rendering from Right to Left direction with animation

Thank You

Comment: Can you edit the question clarify what it is you want as the outcome (e.g. add a picture)? There is some discussion about RTL locales [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3109) and drawing in reverse [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809282/how-to-plot-data-from-right-to-left-in-mpandroidchart) but it's not clear if those are what you are asking about. The chart is usually just x-y points drawn all at once without a "direction" - are you trying to animate the chart filling in from right to left?

Comment: @TylerV, Yes exactly am looking into that but I want to animate drawing in reverse direction as well which I am not able to achieve that using this lineChart.animateX(1000, Easing.EasingOption.Linear)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an easy solution I found without any much code if anyone is looking into it:-

**Inside your XML file add one View on top of line chart like that below:-**

```
    <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
       android:id="@+id/lineChart"
       android:layout_width="400dp"
       android:layout_height="244dp"/>
    
    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/llOverLay"
       android:layout_width="400dp"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:background="@color/white"/>
   </FrameLayout>
```

**Rendered line chart without animation first**

```
lineChart?.invalidate()
```

Then apply reveal animation from right to left which is translate llOverLayView on top of line chart like below

```
lineChart?.doOnLayout {
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.llOverLay, "translationX", -screenWidth).apply {
                                    duration = 1000
                                    start()
}
```

Now this makes Line Chart rendering from right to left and thats it!!

**Please be advised, this approach has one restriction which enforced single or multiple series rendering in one fixed direction. Either forward or reverse direction at the same time.**

Comment: Is this an answer, or an edit to the question?

Comment: @TylerV, I found an answer and updated

Comment: This approach simply flips the rendered image of graph. It wouldn't work if I had two series in the same graph, one of which had to be displayed in reverse.

Comment: @JBM, Thanks for your comment yes agree this only works for one series not for multiple series graph, Even if you have multiple series in the same graph and want to see reverse behavior then this tweak will work. The only case where it won't work is if you want to handle two series rendering in opposite direction. But if you have any better approach then please let me know? As I don't see any better way in the library to handle that